# Analyzing movement data for a checkerboard

Tags: statistics, task-analysis

For a psychology experiment - subject has to learn that the 2D grid is a checkerboard, and collect all the 1s (rewards). How do I test if subjects are actually doing it in the most optimal way -- making least effort for moving from one square to the next by taking smaller steps (or selecting closest reward neighbour). My guess is that if I could simulate a learning algorithm and approximate how long it takes to learn the reward distribution, and then explore it optimally (optimality is defined as a unit of time and exploring closest squares first), I could compare the behaviour.

(i've cross-posted in the game development forum as well, as inputs from both psychologists and game developers would be very useful!)

Comment: Could you give a diagram explaining the task and the ideal behaviour?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is on Optimization, *i.e.*, the realm of computer sciences (along the perimeters of machine learning *etc*.)